# navigator.userAgent different for each browser, what is the meaning of values in it?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, user-agent, navigator

I was very curious to know about values in result of **navigator.userAgent**.

I executed **navigator.userAgent** in **chrome**, **FireFox** and **IE 8**

and results I got are,

```
In IE8 ==> 

     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
     Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
     3.0.30729; InfoPath.2)"

In chrome ==>

     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"

In FireFox ==>

     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
```

Can someone please explain values in each result.

*Thanks in advance..*

Comment: This question is off-topic because it not a specific technical programming related question, and will most likely be closed.

Comment: You can find an amusing but accurate explanation here: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Comment: Thank you GenericJon, it was really helpful link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`navigator.userAgent` returns a string. See the general format for it.

```
userAgent = appCodeName/appVersion number (Platform; Security; OS-or-CPU; 
Localization; rv: revision-version-number) product/productSub 
Application-Name Application-Name-version
```

example : `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Win98; en-US; rv:0.9.2) Gecko/20010725 Netscape6/6.1`

Here

- AppCodeName = Mozilla
- AppVersion number = 5.0
- Platform = Windows
- Security = U ( The type of security encryption included. Possible values are U (128-bit encryption), I (40-bit encryption), and N (no encryption).)
- OS-or-CPU = Win98
- Localization = en-US (Indicate the language used. Here it is US-English).
- Revision-version-number = 0.9.2
- Product = Gecko (The Gecko rendering engine is at the heart of Firefox.)
- ProductVersion = 20010725
- Application-Name = Netscape6
- Application-Version = 6.1

For more details see the [History of the user-agent string](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/)

Comment: superb, This is exactly what i wanted to know. Thank you Sajith